# How do I Configure Search To Remove Student Results?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, onedrive

Hello I would like to know how I can remove student onedrive Results appearing in search . I am using SharePoint 2013 Online with O365. Staff and Student share same tenancy. Is there way to block students one drive appearing in SharePoint search.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by creating the crawl rules in Search Administration where you can restrict the contents that to be shown as part of search results  .

Please refer this for more info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219686.aspx

Comment: I am using SharePoint Online 2013 . I don't have the option to acess Search Administration

Comment: Yes to configure this you should have the access to SharePoint Online Admin page then you can try with configuring the crawl rules, hope your SharePoint Online Admin can help here.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Search does not pick up OneDrive search results if those OneDrive files and folders are private to each user. Same in Delve. Both honor security trimming - which means you only see files you have access to. If students shared their content with others, then it is a different story. Agree with previous comment, you will need to configure/customize search center for this.